# apache2 expires.conf global ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache2

I used to configure previous version of Ubuntu 14.04 a global /etc/apache2/mods-available/expires.conf for the mod_expires module in Apache2.
I've looked for documentations on internet; but all docs tell me use it in the conf of every web site.
There is a way to define it just in one file , and all websites on apache take that config ?